# Passing type hints to a function

Tags: haskell

I want to check that I've implemented an enumeration properly.  That is, I want to confirm that

```
(toEnum . fromEnum) a = a
(fromEnum . toEnum) z = z
```

where a is an instance of my enumerated type and z is an Int.  The first case is okay.

```
> (toEnum . fromEnum) Green == Green
True
```

A boolean-returning function can be written, such as,

```
convertsFromTo :: (Enum a, Eq a) => a -> Bool
convertsFromTo a = (toEnum . fromEnum) a == a
```

and used

```
> convertsFromTo Green
True
```

The second case is trickier as the compiler needs a type hint to know the type of the value to be constructed from the integer.

```
> fromEnum (toEnum 1 :: Colour) == 1
True
```

Is there any way to pass a type hint to a function?

```
convertsToFrom :: ??? -> Int -> Bool
convertsToFrom ??? z = fromEnum (toEnum z :: ???) == z
```

Alternatively, is there a better solution than invoking `toEnum` outside the function?

```
convertsToFrom :: Enum a => a -> Int -> Bool
convertsToFrom a z = fromEnum a == z

> convertsToFrom (toEnum 1 :: Colour) 1
True
```

For completeness,

```
data Colour = Red | Green | Blue deriving (Eq)

instance Enum Colour where
    fromEnum Red   = 0
    fromEnum Green = 1
    fromEnum Blue  = 2
    toEnum       0 = Red
    toEnum       1 = Green
    toEnum       2 = Blue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can work with [**`TypeApplications`** <sup>[ghc-doc]</sup>](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

convertsToFrom :: forall a . Enum a => Int -> Bool
convertsToFrom z = fromEnum (toEnum z :: a) == z
```

then you can use this with `convertsToFrom @Colour` for example.

Comment: that's magic :D  Thank you very much!  Incidentally, the module calling `convertsToFrom` needed _TypeApplications_ and the module declaring needed _ScopedTypeVariables_ and _AllowAmbiguousTypes_.